# How to Count how many records getting form the pages table?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am new in ruby I am getting lots of problem here. I want to count how many record fetch from the `pages` table

Here is my code -

```
@page = Page.find_by_id(1)
#render text: @page.size
#render text: @page.length
#render text: @page.count
if @page.size
   @page_name = @page.page_name
else
   redirect_to root_url
end
```

I am getting error message :

```
undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

Also I have tried to use `length` and `count` same type error message coming. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Base#find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) returns the only one record.

One should use [`ActiveRecord::Base#where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) instead to search for multiple records:

```
@page = Page.where(condition_here)
```

---

#### Using `find`

As clearly specified in the documentation I linked above, `find` method will raise a [`RecordNotFound`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) exception if it fails to look up the record. **To redirect to 404 in case of fail using `find`**:

```
begin
  @page = Page.find_by_id(1)
  @page_name = @page.page_name
rescue RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: No matter about the query. I want to count number of record.

Comment: Updated my question on your answer

Comment: I do not understand what do you want anymore. Now your question is just wrong, because `where` returns a relation object, that apparently **has** `size` method and one can not receive an error you specified. To find the whole amount of records in the table, use `Page.count` as by @Ursus.

Comment: Actually I have an record. Which column name `seo='about-us'` I want to put condition that `about-us` record exist or not. So I want to get the array length will coming 1 then i am sure that my `about-us` exist. other wise redirect to `404` page

Comment: My query - @page = Page.find_by_seo('about-us')

Comment: Then my answer is still perfectly valid: `Page.where(seo: 'about_us').count` will return the count.

Comment: If i am using where. This is working fine. But not working in the `find` statement

Comment: Yes after I have checked your `where` this is working fine. But I want to get same output in `find` condition

Comment: Of course it is not working for `find`. It is not working for `find` **by design**. Go re-read my answer and all the documentation I linked.

Comment: You are write. I am wrong. May I know how to put condition that I am getting result or not. if true then stay this page. otherwise redirect to 404 page

Comment: Updated my question. Please check now

Comment: I am unable to understand why you reject reading the documentation, I linked and many times mentioned above. It would be faster, more effective and after all more descriptive. Please see an update.

Comment: Ruby language new for me so I have getting too many problem. Thank you dear for your answering.